# Gradle WSL: unknown property from buildSrc

Tags: gradle, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a project with a buildSrc that has a package (eg `abc`).

I use that package in my other project `build.gradle` files (eg `abc.test()`). Given that it's under `buildSrc`, it is imported automatically, and it's been working on my macbook.

I am now trying to do the same thing with windows + WSL.

My current setup involves having java and gradle installed in windows (and working via Android Studio), while also having java and gradle installed in WSL. The short story is that WSL's gradle kept complaining about bad java_home paths when they were shared, so I installed everything as if it were pure linux.

When trying to run `gradle build`, the command now complains:

```
> Could not get unknown property 'abc' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Is there a way around this? Is there a better workaround to running gradle tasks from WSL? I'm using this in a pre-commit, so I'm even open to having it run the command "through windows" if it helps. As of now, I suspect it's a pathing issue, because build commands work fine in the IDE.

Comment: Is there a chance that any Windows-based paths are coming before the Linux ones in environment variables (either $PATH, $JAVA_HOME, or anything else)?  When both Windows and Linux versions of a tool are installed, often a Windows path will take precedence over the Linux version, causing problems.  This sounds like it may be the case.

Comment: I've fixed the JAVA_HOME problem by installing it in linux and setting it in zsh (which is set after and is the one I want). The problem now is that the gradle files aren't resolving properly when they should work. I'm unsure if it's related to gradle not knowing the project folder, or if it's some other pathing issue